# Only first elements are visible in list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a `List` of `WebElements` in webpage with specific height-width (that I don't know), and I want to print all the elements shown in that list. Here is my code:

```
public CinemaModule CinemasName() throws InterruptedException
{
    List<WebElement> cinemalist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4.media-heading"));
    System.out.println("Total cinemas are " + cinemalist.size());
    System.out.println("Cinemas names are:- ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cinemalist.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(cinemalist.get(i).getText());
        return new CinemaModule(driver);
    }
}
```

This code gives me `count = 32` but when I get text then it prints only first 4 cinemas text (that are viewable) and for rest of cinemas it prints null (no text) because rest of the cinemas list are under scrolling. For viewing those cinemas name (WebElement) we have to scroll.

How do I print the list of all 32 cinemas?

Comment: try the selenium moveToElement method that in Action class.

Comment: move the `return new CinemaModule(driver);` after for loop

Comment: How can you say that your provided method prints only first 4 cinemas text while it will returns just after first iteration??? are you sure your method is correct???

Comment: Can you share the link to the site you are using?

Comment: @JeffC:- here is the link http://www.pvrcinemas.com/cinemas/Delhi-NCR .....and in the left side it shows cinemas name, i want to print all the cinemas name. thx!!!

Comment: Thanks! Sudharsan Selvarj's answer is correct. I verified his code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScriptExecuter's executeScript() method to scroll the particular element into view and then use getText() method to obtains the text from the element.

try the below code,

```
public CinemaModule CinemasName() throws InterruptedException
{
    List<WebElement> cinemas = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4.media-heading"));
    System.out.println("Total cinemas are " + cinemas.size());
    System.out.println("Cinemas names are:- ");
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    for (WebElement cinema : cinemas)
    {
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", cinema);
        System.out.println("  " + cinema.getText());
    }

    return new CinemaModule(driver);
}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format and indent your code. You can have your editor do this for you and just paste it into the answer making sure that all lines have at least 4 spaces in front.

Comment: It will do nothing actually because element already found in the list and iterating.. in this case if element will change due to scrolling, sure it will throw stale exception...

Comment: I cleaned up the answer a little to make it a little more efficient and fix the indents to make it more readable. This answer works... I tried it once OP posted his URL.

Answer (score -1):

Without being able to see the site itself I'm not sure but it looks like one big issue is you are returning from this function before the loop is complete. You have the return inside the `for` loop. Move it after the `for` loop and see if that fixes the issue.

```
public CinemaModule CinemasName() throws InterruptedException
{
    List<WebElement> cinemalist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4.media-heading"));
    System.out.println("Total cinemas are " + cinemalist.size());
    System.out.println("Cinemas names are:- ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cinemalist.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(cinemalist.get(i).getText());
    }
    return new CinemaModule(driver);
}
```

I don't know what `CinemaModule` is but you didn't set anything in this function so I'm not sure what it's returning. If all you are doing is printing the list of cinemas, you shouldn't need to return anything so you can change the return type to `void`... but I can't see your code so maybe you need this???

Comment: I think user actually forgot to move return outside the loop during post question...you can point out it with the comment instead of providing answer...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur if I do that and it solves the problem then the question gets left without an answer. That's why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think this is the actual OP's problem, because he mention clearly that it **prints only first 4 cinemas text**. while provided methods will print only one iteration

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I agree... that's why I stated that this seems to be one of the issues.

Comment: Now i have a list of movies name in Android application and i am writing my script in appium(using java):- i am getting same problem while getting names of all the movies, It only prints movies name that are visible and rest of the movies name are under scrolling. When i apply the same code, appium throws error about javascriptExecutor(yet not implemented). So please suggest how to get all the name of shown movies from a list.

Comment: If you have a different question, please post it as a new question. Be sure to click accept on one of the answers here if they helped you solve this question too.